# Magento template for attribute set tab in product editor?

Tags: magento, select

What is the template of attribute set page / tab in product editor?

I created some attributes that are multi-select and assigned them to an attribute set. And when I'm editing products that are assigned to this attribute set, on the attribute set tab, all the multi-select controls have a fixed height of 10 rows (size="10").

I want them to not be fixed but rather as long as need to be, because there are a lot of options in some of the selects and it annoys my editor to have to scroll down to find a particular option.

I tried to search by this:

```
find adminhtml -type f -exec grep -l " size=\"10\"" {} \;
```

but no luck, also tried:

```
find adminhtml -type f -exec grep -l " multiple=\"multiple\"" {} \;
```

and still no luck. What I found didn't seem the template I needed.

So which template it is that I should edit to remove the property size="10" for all the multi-select of the attribute set tab in product editor?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make the change inside the template in adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml

```
<td class="value">
    <?php if ($_element->getSize()==10)$_element->setSize(20);//here the change?>
    <?php echo trim($this->getElementHtml()) ?>
    <?php if ($_element->getNote()) : ?>
        <p class="note"><?php echo $_element->getNote() ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Default size is set into class, not in template:

```
class Varien_Data_Form_Element_Multiselect extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
{
    public function __construct($attributes=array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->setType('select');
        $this->setExtType('multiple');
        $this->setSize(10);
    }
..................
}
```

if you want to change that you should observe `adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form` event. Then in your observer you can do something like this

```
foreach ($form->getElements() as $element) {
   if ($element instanceof Varien_Data_Form_Element_Multiselect) {
       $element->setSize(/*your value*/);
   }
}
```